# Knockout click binding with javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, confirm

I can't figure out how to create a knockout click binding that doesn't execute the valueAccessor unless a javascript confirm dialog returns true.

It's probably look something like this:

```
<a data-bind="confirmClick: { message: 'Are you sure?', click: someMethod }">Confirmable link</a>
```

Internally, the confirmClick binding would do something like:

```
if (confirm(message)) {
   click();
}
```

I know I could get around having to do this by putting the `confirm(...)` code in my 
viewModel, but that doesn't seem like the appropriate place to put that kind of code. I could probably also go as far as to do this kind of confirm dialog with jQueryUI or Bootstrap, but I want something I can just drop into any project.

I've scoured the internets with no luck.. I even looked at the source code for knockout's click event (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js), but it doesn't look friendly at all...

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to create your custom `confirmClick` [binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) which takes your message and your click handler and wrap around the confirmation logic:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.confirmClick = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var message = ko.unwrap(value.message);
        var click = value.click;
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: function () {
            if (confirm(message))
                return click.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
        }}, viewModel);
    }
}
```

And you can you it like you have described:

```
<a data-bind="confirmClick: { message: 'Are you sure?', click: someMethod }">
    Confirmable link</a>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Lrjdba/).

Note: You only need the `click.apply` magic if you want to preserve and pass over the original `click` event handler args to your own click event handler.

Comment: Just to finalize things.... what should the anonymous `click:function() { ....}` return if confirm returns false?

Comment: it will return `undefined` so KO won't call your handler also the browser action (clicking on the link) won't be executed. But you can change this according to your needs.

Comment: Already tested this before the other answer came in and it works incredibly well. I'm glad I spent the time investigating how to do it on my own, but I didn't get anywhere close to this level of enlightenment. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, small bug in your code. The third parameter of init is `allBindings` not `viewModel`. Your JSFiddle works because you do not use the `vm` parameter in your final method.

Comment: If you need to use the viewModel in your click event, you can pass it to the click.apply function. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Lrjdba/17/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is where Knockout defines the click binding handler -

```
ko.bindingHandlers[eventName] = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            var result = {};
            result[eventName] = valueAccessor();
            return result;
        };
        return ko.bindingHandlers['event']['init'].call(this, element, newValueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Where eventName is 'click' for that binding handler.  I believe that putting this somewhere in your view model or after Knockout is loaded should do the trick -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickConfirm = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            var result = {};
            result.click = function () {
             var result = confirm('You are about to confirm something.');
                // If they press OK,
                console.log('pressed - ', result);
                if (result === true) {
                    console.log('Calling this - ', valueAccessor());
                    valueAccessor()();
                }

            }
            return result;
        };
        return ko.bindingHandlers['event']['init'].call(this, element, newValueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XhLKD/

Comment: Kudos on the working solution, but @nemesv's answer came in first, works, and at least appears to be a slightly simpler solution. I should point out that there are things happening in both of your solutions that are outside my understanding, so, from a technical perspective, your answer might very well be better. Ultimately, I picked the first, and shorter answer based on my ignorance.